# How to Write Sql Expression with where condition in Crystal Reports

Tags: sql, sql-server, crystal-reports

Hi i am new to Crystal reports. Here is my simple SQL Query.

```
SELECT        SUM(dbo.emp_acc_credit.pfund)
FROM            dbo.emp_acc_credit
where (emp_acc_credit.EID = @eid)
```

I want to write it in Crystal reports Sql Expression. Here '@eid' is the id of each employ and in my report it is showing detail of all employs one by one means on one page we have all detail record of one employ.

How can i assign that EID?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you have is returning just one single value.  Also, where is @eid coming from?  If you want the sum of all the EID's then you can do this, which will return the employeeId and the sum for that employee:

```
SELECT emp_acc_credit.EID, SUM(dbo.emp_acc_credit.pfund)
FROM   dbo.emp_acc_credit
WHERE  emp_acc_credit.EID = @eid
GROUP BY emp_acc_credit.EID
```

To return the sum for all employees:

```
SELECT emp_acc_credit.EID, SUM(dbo.emp_acc_credit.pfund)
FROM   dbo.emp_acc_credit
GROUP BY emp_acc_credit.EID
```